# Failing a jenkins job

Tags: java, jenkins

I have a .Jar file that will just load data into database when it's run. I have scheduled to run this job via Jenkins. When I execute the job in Jenkins it runs the .JAR successfully. However say if there is a null pointer exception in the job and it did not complete successfully. Even then Jenkins says that job has "Passed". How do I fail the job if there is an issue during the job execution?

Comment: How do you "run" the jar file?

Comment: It's an executable jar. So I jus did java -jar  writer.jar   in jenkins "configure job" section

Comment: does the jar call System.exit?

Comment: no it doesn't.. how do I do that @BevynQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Corey's solution is good. And if you don't want to write a JUnit test and support it in Jenkins, you can just do what he alluded to earlier: catch the null-pointer exception (really, just have a top-level catch in your app), and call the API to exit with a return code:

```
try {
    myCode.call();
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("An exception was caught at the top level:" + e);
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Last time I had this problem, I decided to take a different tack and changed the program call into a junit test.  Jenkins was quite happy then.

```
Steps I took:
1. create an empty (maven) project
2. added a single java class SmokeTest.java
3. Added test that called the method I was testing via a script
4. Create a (maven) Jenkins job to run the project
```

Contents of my test:

```
public class SmokeTest
{
    private static final String OK = "OK"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver
        final WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        final String url = PropertyManager.getInstance().getString(PropertyManager.SMOKE_TEST_URL_BASE) + "smoke/smoketest"; //$NON-NLS-1$
        AuditLog.registerEvent("Smoke test url is: " + url, this.getClass(), AuditLog.INFO); //$NON-NLS-1$
        driver.get(url);

        // Find the text element by its id
        final WebElement databaseElement = driver.findElement(By.id("database")); //$NON-NLS-1$

        final String databaseResult = databaseElement.getText();
        Assert.assertEquals(SmokeTest.OK, databaseResult);

        //Close the browser
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

The most important part here is the "Assert.assertEquals" line. The result of this is pickup by jUnit and therefore jenkins

Comment: In my case I had access to the source code, so I could just call the method and watch the return.   If you really wanted to hack, I guess you could open the jar and try to find what to call from the manifest file.  Sorry thats not much help :(

Comment: I wrote the code and created the JAR. So I have access to everything..  So what exactly needs to be done here? thanks

Comment: Added some example code for you.  Changed the contents of the test() method and you should be good to go

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins jobs fails if the exit code is anything but zero.

```
System.exit(1);
```

Should work (or fail, to be more precise :-)